How to precisely track the physical page allocation of a process in linux, including the page table and normal pages
There are numerous cases where the kernel allocates physical memory for a process. Clearly, it envolves virtual memory related exception and syscalls. I would like to precisely track the allocation of those physical memory pages, such that we can do something interesting. However, the kernel is so complex that I can not enumerate all the cases. Simply using the mmu_notifier is not enough, as many cases do not raise a notify event. Any help would be appraciated.
I intercept the virtual memory related syscalls and exceptions, and also utilized the mmu_notifier. But it is not enough, as the speculative pre-allocated physical pages can not be easily tracked based on the faulting address.
